# Sharepoint 2013 Online SQL Server Connect

Tags: web-services, sql-server

We have a sharepoint 2013 online tenant. We have some sql server databases that are on premise.

For this query we want to connect sharepoint 2013 online to those databases and read information from them and display this data on Sharepoint 2013 online. This will give users on user interface to everywhere.

What is the best and most secure way to do this?

Would it be beneficial to move these databases to azure to make this task a lot simpler?

Currently we are not sure how to connect these up.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to Azure SQL might make things simpler, but [this technet article details a Hybrid BCS Solution for SharePoint Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197239(v=office.15).aspx).

This picture details how the configuration ends up, in case the article goes away (unlikely)
[image: Picture detailing hybrid configuration]